# Query that retrieves combinations from two sequential rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (time_period)

The table lists several time periods like so.

```
unique_id         type_id          sequence_number     billing_id   ...
    13              LJK1             1                  4356
    14              CNS3             2                  4356
    15              LJK1             3                  4356
    16              AOX4             4                  4356
    17              CNS3             1                  9827
    18              POD2             2                  9827
```

It gets tricky. I need to return all the type_id pairs from one period to the next period based on incrementing sequence numbers. For example, for billing_id='4356', I need to retrieve this resultset

```
-----------------------------------
LJK1       | CNS3                 -- type_ids pair from seq 1 to seq 2
CNS3       | LJK1                 -- type_ids pair from seq 2 to seq 3
LJK1       | AOX4                 -- type_ids pair from seq 3 to seq 4
```

The count of sequence_numbers per order is variable (as high as 10, as low as 2). I'll be doing this for X number of orders. From this, I'll be doing further processing, but getting these pairings itself is puzzling me. I don't need order_id or sequence numbers in the resultset.

Are recursive CTEs needed here? Perhaps cursors? Or maybe using pivot? I've just been brainstorming and researching, but I'm not too experienced with any of those and could use some direction.

Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why do you need the pairs in the SQL response instead of listing the typeid's in ascending order and pairing them programatically in the display?

Comment: are the sequence_numbers ... sequential?

Comment: This is used in reporting in a custom application that has very limited options for customizing the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need a recursive CTE nor cursors. Try this:

```
    SELECT A.type_id, B.type_id
    FROM time_period A
    LEFT JOIN time_period B
    ON A.billing_id = B.billing_id
    AND A.sequence_number = B.sequence_number - 1
    WHERE A.billing_id = 4356
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see why this works now. Just tested this and it's exactly correct. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

(works even if `sequence_number(s)` are not sequential)

```
    SELECT a.type_id, b.type_id
      FROM table a
 LEFT JOIN table b
        ON b.billing_id = a.billing_id
       AND b.sequence_number = (SELECT max(sequence_number)
                                  FROM table
                                 WHERE sequence_number < a.sequence_number
                                   AND billing_id = a.billing_id)
     WHERE a.billing_id = 4356
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select lt.typeid as l_typeid, rt.typeid as r_typeid
from time_period lt inner join time_period rt on
lt.billing_id = rt.billing_id and lt.sequence_number = rt.sequence_number -1
```

Edited to "lt" and "rt" aliases as "left" and "right" may be reserved words.

Comment: I probably would have used +1, but it's a style thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.billing_id, l.type_id, r.type_id
FROM time_period AS l
INNER JOIN time_period AS r
    ON r.sequence_number = l.sequence_number + 1
    AND r.billing_id = l.billing_id
ORDER BY l.billing_id, l.sequence_number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    tp.[type_id] as 'First Period',
    tp1.[type_id] as 'Second Period'
from 
    time_period tp
join
   time_period tp1 
on
   tp.billing_id = tp1.billing_id
where
   tp.billing_id = '4356'
and
   (tp.sequence_number + 1) = tp1.sequence_number
```

Not sure if it's more efficient to get it all the information and pair programatically, but your original question can be achieved with the above.

**Edit: Corrected my column names to match those in the original question**